# Freeform return_url with SUBMISSION_ID doesn't return to a page with an ID number

Tags: solspace-freeform

The docs for Freeform say the `return_url` should look like `return_url="{path='my/template/submission/SUBMISSION_ID'}"` but when I do that I end up on a page with URL = `/my/template/submission/SUBMISSION_ID`, i.e. `SUBMISSION_ID` doesn't get replaced with an actual ID.

I've also tried installing the demo templates which have the same and submitted the form, and get the same result.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing submission data for the form? Please make sure to have the **Store Submitted Data** setting checked off inside the Settings tab in the form builder. Otherwise, this feature will not work correctly.

If that isn't the issue here, please [submit a support ticket](https://docs.solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/v1/support.html) with more details and we can help you troubleshoot there. :)

Comment: Does checked off mean that it should be checked (i.e. on), or not checked? It's checked on and submissions have been stored in the database.

Comment: Sorry, by "checked off" I meant "checked" / checked on. You'll probably need to send us a support ticket with more information :)